# MacBook Air won't maintain a good wifi connection but iPhone does?

Tags: wifi, macbook-pro, internet

Both my MacBook Air and iPhone are connected to the Internet using my home Wifi connection. Whilst my iPhone loads up google, YouTube, Maps an other apps that use the Internet just fine. My MacBook Air will not maintain its connection to the Internet and when it does it is very, very slow (1.7Mbps). I've set the service order correctly in System Preferences > Network.

I can't upload and screenshots as I'm posting this via iPhone. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

If your Router has two different antennas sending on different frequencies, see if your iPhone uses a different one as your Air, and if so, try to connect to the other one.